# How can I prevent 404 error show up in console when API link is wrong in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So for example I fetch `https://api.github.com/users/{user input}` and the user input is a Github username that doesn't exist. How can I prevent 404 error show up in console but display an warning to the user that it's a wrong username.

Comment: use `try`with `catch`.

Comment: Unfortunately the closest thing you can get that I've found is `console.clear();`. This is obviously imperfect because I would prefer to show all other console messages above. I wish there was a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Using catch:

```
    fetch(url).then((response) => {
      if (response.ok) {
        return response.json();
      } else {
        throw new Error('Something went wrong');
      }
    })
    .then((responseJson) => {
      // Do something with the response
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    });
```

Or try/catch:

```
try {
         fetch(url).then((response) => {
          if (response.ok) {
            return response.json();
          } else {
            throw new Error('Something went wrong');
          }
        })
        .then((responseJson) => {
          // Do something with the response
        })
    } catch(err) {
    console.log(err)
    }
```

Comment: GET https://api.github.com/users/AFsafafsf%20as%20fasf 404 (Not Found), still shows up in the console. I'm wondering how others deal with this error when the input that user gave to the API is wrong?

Comment: If you control the server, you can return a payload containing the request (positive or negative) e.g. payload tells you "userExists:true"/userExists:false". This way you always get a 200 response (which is technically correct), and if a 404 truly happens then you know the actual request route is failing (what a 404 is naturally supposed to indicate). If you DON'T control the server then you either live with the 404's or you make a proxy which you can control (and always return a 200 with payload).